# How to copy data between two vectors faster?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, multiple-columns, na

I have a data frame with 3 columns (`username, IP_Address, IP_type`).

The column `IP_Address` has some `NA` values.

for each row in `IP_Address`, if the value is `NA`, I want to copy the corresponding value from the column, `username`.

I am using the following code, but it is running very slow. I have 230,000 rows of data, but after one hour it is only halfway through.

Why is it very slow ? How can I do this more efficiently ?

```
for (i in 1:length(log_data$IP_type)) {
   if (is.na(log_data$IP_address[i]) == TRUE ){
       log_data$IP_address[i] <- log_data$user_name[i]  
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R is an interpreted language, so vectorized operations are almost always faster than operations that involve loops.

Find the indices (rows) which have NAs in the address, then assign only those values:

```
na_address <- which(is.na(log_data$IP_address))
log_data$IP_address[na_address] <- log_data$user_name[na_address]
```